# How do I give nuxt-mail a variable email to send to?

Tags: vue.js, nodemailer, nuxtjs3

So Iam trying to use nuxt-mail to send an Email after a user filled out the form. One Email should be mine and the other one should be sent to the one he puts in the email field, so that he can get the confirmation that the email was send. BUT the problem is I have to define the Email it is send to in the nuxt.config.js which means its not variable on what he puts in the form.
How can I give it an additional variable Email to send to?

I have my nuxt.config.js: (smtp data is genereted by Ethereal so its dummy data and not sensitive rn)

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss', '@pinia/nuxt', ['nuxt-mail', {
    message: {
      to: 'abc@abc.com',
    },
    smtp: {
      host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
      port: 587,
      auth: {
        user: 'charles.kilback43@ethereal.email',
        pass: 'eAWgGNgmeBH95ce9Sm'
    }
    },
  }]],
})
```

and i call it like this:

```
<script>

export default {
  methods: {
    sendEmail() {
      this.$mail.send({
        from: 'John Doe',
        subject: 'Incredible',
        text: 'This is an incredible test message',
      })
    },
  },
}

</script>
```

this works fine and sends to abc@abc.de but I need to somehow add another email adress it should send to
I tried it like this:

```
<script>

export default {
  methods: {
    sendEmail() {
      this.$mail.send({
        message:{
            to:'xyz@xyz.de'
        },
        from: 'John Doe',
        subject: 'Incredible',
        text: 'This is an incredible test message',
      })
    },
  },
}

</script>
```

I also tried this:

```
<script>

export default {
  methods: {
    sendEmail() {
      this.$mail.send({
        to:'xyz@xyz.de',
        from: 'John Doe',
        subject: 'Incredible',
        text: 'This is an incredible test message',
      })
    },
  },
}

</script>
```

but this didnt work. So is there any other way to do this?

Comment: It's not a solvable question because it's a limitation of the library.  The library author is of the opinion that a dynamic `to` address is [liable to promote spam](https://github.com/dword-design/nuxt-mail/issues/68) and will not implement such a feature. Their advice is to implement a solution yourself or use a different library.  In that github thread someone did make a pull request with the dynamic addressing but you would need to use that specific branch of the library as it's unlikely to ever be merged.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send mail, then I suggest you go with Nodemailer; it's easy to use, and Nodemailer is a widely used and versatile library for sending emails.